# Output the input of a lambda when triggered?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a very simple piece of lambda code (written in java), and the trigger is based on a "PUT" in an S3 bucket. It listens directly to the bucket via the Lambda trigger dashboard.

There are two questions here, that might help me get my input logged by the lambda :

1 ) Since this is a trigger pointed directly at S3 from the lambda dashboard, show the first argument of my lambda be something OTHER than an SNSEvent? Is this a different type of event? If so, what am I looking for - because I need this to be directly triggered in the way I have this configured.

2 ) Once I have the right object in that signature, do I simple LOG.info the object to see it in monitoring? or do I need to do some other magic

EDIT : Since I mentioned the signature - here is right now :

```
public static void lambdaMethod(SNSEvent input, Context context) throws IOException {
```

I am not sure if that first argument is correct, for a direct trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *S3Event*.

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.S3Event;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.event.S3EventNotification.S3EventNotificationRecord;

public class S3EventProcessorTest implements
        RequestHandler<S3Event, String> {

    public String handleRequest(S3Event s3event, Context context) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

See the *`Java section`* of this [s3-example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html) for a reference.

As far as logging is concerned, You can configure `Log4j`  and use its methods `logger.error(), logger.debug() and logger.log()` to send events to *CloudWatch Logs* or you can just use `System.out.println()` as well.

See this [Logging (Java)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-logging.html) for more details.